# Simple decryption in swift with key & dictionary?

Tags: swift, encryption

looking for a push in the right direction on a minor non problem but more curiosity driven search.

I'm trying to take a ton of text which has been "encrypted" with a plain as day key using uppercase, lowercase & numbers.
ie.

```
Array('1'=>'h', '0'=>'L', '3'=>'H',....
```

Stumbling around my brain trying to think if there was a way to build a dictionary with the value / key as has ben provided can I enter the encrypted text and reference the dictionary for the answer to output decrypted text?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code that you have written to attempt to solve the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the mapping is 1:1, ie, 1 character maps to 1 character, ie no numbers are greater than 9. This should work:

```
let cypher = ["1": "h",
              "0": "L"] as [Character: Character]
             //Add more here as needed.

let yourText = "014"

let decypheredText = yourText.map { char in
    return cypher[char] ?? "?" //Untranslatable things mpa to ?
}.joined()
```

Comment: How is it pointless? `let cypher = ["1": "h",
              "0": "L"] as [Character: Character]` is the same as `let cypher: [Character: Character] = ["1": "h",
              "0": "L"]`

Comment: How is it not the same? Honest question mate. No need to get snarky about it :/